# How to add custom information to CEL records for a call?

Tags: asterisk

With a CDR, is easy to add a custom field.

```
[exit]
exten = s,1,NoOp()
same => n,Set(CDR(my_custom_field)=${SOME_VARIABLE})
same => n,Dial(PJSIP/phone1&DAHDI/17,30,tTkK)
same => n,Hangup()
```

All I have to do is add `my_custom_field` as a column to the `cdr` table and it will be populated.

I want to replicate this with CEL, but altering the table and setting the `CHANNEL(my_custom_field)` item doesn't work, the column is always `NULL`. I can use this:

```
same => n,Set(CHANNEL(userfield)=${SOME_VARIABLE})
```

But I want to use a custom field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom CEL event. But you can't add column. You can add event(new row)

```
CELGenUserEvent(event-name,[extra])
```

Extra can be any text you want.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_CELGenUserEvent

After that you can parse your CEL table and update any field you want to update.